# How to limit characters but keep line breaks/formatting?

Tags: silverstripe

I am using the standard `Content` field that is automatically generated by default to add some text.

```
"Content" => "HTMLText"
```

If I use a limiting function e.g

```
$Content.BigSummary(300)
```

This limits the words but doesn't keep the line breaks. Aka strips the HTML out.

Looking through the framework code, there is `ContextSummary()`

```
public function ContextSummary($characters = 500, $string = false, $striphtml = true, $highlight = true,
            $prefix = "... ", $suffix = "...")
```

However upon testing, using this on an HTMLText field doesn't seem to work, it limits the characters but it doesn't keep the HTML unless the field type is `Text` e.g

**HTMLText:**

`$Content.ContextSummary(200, false, false)` - Strips HTML still

**Text:**

`$Content.ContextSummary(200, false, false)` - Keeps HTML (Which is what I want)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there another function I can use to achieve what I want? Or create a custom function?

Comment: This is a strange situation, because how can `ContextSummary` both limit the number of characters AND retain HTML, when it could very easily break a tag by not returning its closing tag? Even with `<br>` line breaks, you still have the risk of returning `...lazy dog</b` and breaking your DOM

Comment: You might be able to implement your own method to do this by word count, and be very careful not to filter out closing tags after the last word (including nested HTML!)

Comment: The response from Robbie wouldn't appear to be accurate. Having just hacked HTMLTextTest (Line 310 in SS 3.5.1) the ContextSummary() method seems to take account of a string containing markup, and as such, will only count non-markup characters.

This doesn't explain the OP's problem, but there's also casting to take account of which I don't fully understand right now. (See the $casting array in both Text and HTMLText)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with conversion to simple text and back to html - <br> tags are lost as I encountered once. This is a similar hack I used.

```
// override ContextSummary from the Page_Controller
public function ContextSummary($field = 'Content', $characters = 500, $string = false) {
  $content = $this->dbObject($field);
  $content->setValue(str_replace('<br>', '__br__', $content->getValue);
  $summary = $content->ContextSummary($characters, $string, $stripHtml = false);
  return str_replace('__br__', '<br>', $summary);
}

and use $ContextSummary(Content) instead of $Content.ContextSummary in template
```

Comment: this is something related to text conversion with br changed to new line char and `Convert::html2raw` stripping whitespace.

Comment: I just gave this a go and it doesn't seem to work. No text is displayed, I see there is an end bracket missing aswell (I tried to edit but wouldn't let me), should be `$content->setValue(str_replace('<br>', '__br__', $content->getValue))`